# Upload ssl certs using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, terraform

I have an existing ssl cert, private key and intermediate certs (obtained using openssl). Not through aws. I want to upload them now using terraform. I found https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/3560 that you can upload existing certs. But not able to find an example on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. The document was not very clear on how the arguments need to be passed.

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "tch-cert" {
  private_key=file("private.key")
 certificate_body = file("actual_cert.cer")
  certificate_chain=file("inter.cer")
    }
```